# What is Russian term for 'mobbing'?

Tags: выбор-слова, выражения, узус

I'm curious how to render in Russian this specific term.

I think *травля* has subtones of victimity, while mobbed people do tend to fight back, and *гонения* is too obsolete and politicized a word. Besides, that word would be out of the work-life context.

I've been also thinking about *подлость* or *пакости(ть)* as Russian cognates like 'They've been mobbed'  = "*Им (на)пакостили (на работе)*", but, again, this is too emotional a word while mobbing stands for professional/interpersonal things between an individual and a group.

So, how to say 'mobbing' in Russian without getting into long strings of words?

Comment: Well, there is a loanword - моббинг. However, this doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: There's the "навешали" word (as in "Ему вчера на работе навешали, вот он и злится."). However, I would strongly recommend against using this word because it implies a rather nasty invective.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **издевательство**:

> На работе он постоянно терпит издевательства со стороны коллег.
>   На работе над ним постоянно издеваются.

About your request for translation of *"They've been mobbed"* in perfect tense, I want to say that in this case  **Их подставили** is often used.

However, as far as I know, this refers to career only (i.e. one can't say **Его в школе подставили**, that would sound weird ). The noun associated with this verb is **подстава**.

Comment: I think that "их подставили" is closer to "they've been framed" than to "they've been mobbed".

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching for **mobbing** as **bullying** term, maybe word `наезд` would suit you well.

> Меня задолбало терпеть их наезды.

However, I would personally prefer to use a verb when trying to descript **bullying**, because of much more options. So, you can use a verb `наезжать`.

> На меня постоянно все наезжают.

You could also use a profanity `доебываться`, a good old phrase `катить бочку` and a jargonic `крошить батон`.

Comment: Isn't крошить батон too obsolete a phrase?

Comment: @Manjusri no, it's not obsolete, however now it's more often used in ironic context

Answer (score 2):

[**Гноби́ть**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_2486), загноби́ть — травить, угнетать, притеснять, изводить, приставать, давить, преследовать, докучать, надоедать, раздражать, несправедливо критиковать с целью выжать с места или устранить из круга конкурентов.

[**Третировать**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F2%F0%E5%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%F2%FC&all=x) — обращаться с кем-либо пренебрежительно, свысока, враждебно и агрессивно; не считаться с кем-либо.

**Чмори́ть, [чмари́ть](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_16039), [чмыри́ть](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_16054)** (школьный, подростковый сленг) ~ гнобить

Comment: Если цитируете из словаря, указывайте ссылку, пожалуйста.

Comment: @theUg added links to gramota.ru

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, one term was omitted from the previous answers. Similar to *гнобить* there is a verb *клевать*, which literally means “to peck”, and figuratively often used in a sense that this question is inquiring about:

> Совсем заклевали бедолагу!

That figurative meaning of this verb (in its perfective aspect) stems from the practise of some species of birds to peck the weak and the ill amongst themselves to death when there is not enough feed, or simply to rid the flock from the weakest link.